# Encoding Error with Maven UTF-Encoding when executing buildjob via Jenkins Script

Tags: maven, jenkins, spring-boot

So I have a maven build for a spring project that works without problem when executing the maven commands directly. I also set the UTF-8 encoding like this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

and

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

However, when the Jenkins Build job is executed n the  it creates a temporary shell file with the mvn commands in it. When this file is executed an encoding problem occurs:

```
     Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.5:war 
(default-war) on project ChalltellServer: Execution default-war of goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.5:war failed: Malformed input or 
input contains unmappable chacraters: /.../aa?aa.JPG
```

When I check the locale of the mac I get

```
locale   
LANG=                                                  
LC_COLLATE="C"                                         
LC_CTYPE="C"                                           
LC_MESSAGES="C"                                        
LC_MONETARY="C"                                        
LC_NUMERIC="C"                                         
LC_TIME="C"                                            
LC_ALL=
```

Could it be necessry to change this?

Comment: The error message looks like you have some filenames encoded not in the encoding you have defined on the OS you are running jenkins on....You should change the encoding to UTF-8....

Comment: That's what I thought too, I just don't understand why it only causes problems when the mvn command is run inside a .sh file...